# Possible Wave Conundrum

Tags: waves, acoustics, frequency, interference

Say I have a giant fidget spinner that can spin at 400 Hz. I then attach 3 sound sources, i.e speakers, and play a 400 Hz pure tone. What would happen if the spinner spins at the same frequency as the tone or even higher?

Comment: -1. Not clear what you are asking, and no research effort. Please be more specific about what you mean by "what would happen?" What are you expecting to happen? What is the conundrum?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The movement of the speaker (through a fidget spinner or any other means) will result in doppler shift at a stationary listening position. The amount of shift is simply a function of the ratio instantaneous speed of the speaker to the speed of sound in air.

In case of the spinner the speaker is on a circular path so you will get a roughly sinusoidal frequency modulation with the perceived frequency highest at the location closest to the microphone and lowest at the position furthest away from the microphone.

If the speaker reaches the speed of sound (ca. 344 meters per second), the math gets weird and the resulting frequency becomes infinity (approaching the listener). The actual result is a sonic boom.